# How are critical values derived for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test?

Tags: statistics

One appealing feature of the K-S test is that it is distribution-free. So this leads to my question - how are the critical values for the K-S derived, then? Is there a way to express the critical values as an integral, like for percentiles of the standard normal distribution?

Sources that have such information would be very helpful (i.e., a textbook).

See, for example, the table below (from http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~lipschultz/cs1538/prob-table_KS.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: Here it is: http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~lipschultz/cs1538/prob-table_KS.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are testing fit to a specific distribution, then note that for a sample of data $X$ and hypothesized distribution $F, F^{-1}(X) \sim U(0,1)$. Therefore, you need to derive the distribution of the largest vertical difference between your *transformed* sample and the hypothesized CDF, which will be taken to be the standard uniform. The distribution of this is not mathematically nice. [Here](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/Kolmogorovsmirnov.pdf) is a paper that walks you though why...and why we just use numerical methods.